# Proving restriction of function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The problem is:

> If $f : (X, T) \to (Y, S) $ is continuous and $A \subseteq X$, then $f|_A : (A, T_A) \to(Y, S) $ is continuous.

How would I get started on this proof? I understand the restriction of the function $f$ is $f|_A(x) = f(x) $ for all $x\in A $. I jut don't see how to use this to show that it is continuous.

Comment: How do you check continuity? Take an arbitrary open $V \subseteq Y$ and see if $f|_A^{-1}[V]$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has the subspace topology, then $f^{-1}(U)$  is open for any $U \subset Y$ that is open. But then $f^{-1}(U) \cap A$ is open in $A$, but $f^{-1}(U) \cap A$ is precisely$\dots$

Comment: If I understood... Her's my attempt at a "Formal" proof: Let $f:X,T→Y,S$ be continuous and $A⊆X$. We will show that $f|_A:(A,τ_A )→(Y,S)$ is continuous.
Note that if A has the subspace topology then $f^{-1} (U)$ is open for any $U⊂Y$ that is open. But, $f^{-1} (U)∩A$ is open in $A$ and $f^{-1} (U)∩A=\{x∈X |  f(x)∈U \}∩A= \{x∈X |  f|_A (x)∈U \}= f^{-1} |_A (U) $. 
Now, by definition of a continuous function we must have that for all $V∈S$ we have that $f^{-1} (V)∈τ_A$. As noted $f^{-1} (U)∩A=f^{-1}|_A (U)$ is open in $A$ and thus $f|_A:(A,τ_A  )→(Y,S)$ is continuous. □

Comment: @Overflow2341313 why did you start in MathJax and then do some very strange thing?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I think it's tough to read, but the argument goes through.

Comment: Should be fixed. Tried to expand your 'precisely...' bit back to the definition of continous. Not sure I've actually achieved this.

Comment: Basically the first equation in your last sentence is all that was missing. It's clear that it is open by the definition of the subspace topology.