# Topological continuity and open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the answer in this thread below:

[Proving restriction of function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568165/proving-restriction-of-function-is-continuous)

The author of the answer says "$f^{-1}(U) \cap A$ is open in $A$ ".

We have

$f^{-1}_A(U) = \{a \in A: f_A(a) \in U\} \underbrace{=}_{f = f_A \text{ on }A} \{a \in A: f(a) \in U\} = f^{-1}(U)$

By definition of $f_A$, we have $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq A.$ So, what's the point of saying (over-specifying?) $f^{-1}(U) \cap A$ is open instead of just saying $f^{-1}(U)$ is open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is$$f^{-1}(U)=\{\color{blue}{x\in X}:f(x)\in U\}\\f^{-1}_A(U)=\{x\in A:f(x)\in U\}=f^{-1}(U)\cap A$$So $f^{-1}(U)$ is not necessarily a subset of $A$. It is actually $f^{-1}_A(U)$ that is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

that is because you misinterpretated the answer. The author expressed the restriction $f_{|_A}$ in terms of $f$ not restricted: for an arbitrary open $U$ in $Y$ we get:
$$f^{-1}_{|_A}(U)=f^{-1}(U)\cap A$$
thus $f_{|_A}$ is continous by the very definition of subspace topology.

Comment: As I am studying real analysis, I am not yet familiar with subspace topology. Can you run the definition of subspace topology by me again, please.  Suppose $X = (-10, 10), A = [-5, 5], f^{-1}(U) = (-3, 7).$ Then $f^{-1}(U) \cap A= [-5, 5]$, correct? What's happening here? Is $A$ always supposed to be open?

Comment: Matter of fact no. Subspace topology means every open of $A$ is the intersection of $A$ with an open in $X$.  Thus $f^{-1}(U)\cap A=(-3,5]$ which as odd as it can seem, is open in $A$ by def. of subspace top.